# How to customize icons for running applications (seen in alt-tab)?

Tags: icons

I often have many terminal windows open and switch between them with alt-tab.  Right now, they are all shown as the black "utilities-terminal" icon.  I would like to customize the icons so I can easily switch between them - how?

I've tried creating custom .desktop entries and changing the Icon there.  But, that only changes the icon to launch the terminal.  Once running, it is shown as normal icon again.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, what version of Ubuntu are you using? On 11.10 (and probably 11.04 and 12.04) the alt-tab switcher groups windows by default.

Anyway, if you're looking to give terminal instances individual icons, I doubt that's possible apart from hacking Unity. If you're just looking to change the terminal, I believe you can locate your icon folder (sometimes at /usr/share/icons, other times at ~/.icons) and drop in a custom "terminal" image of the appropriate name and it should take effect the next time you log in.

Does this address your issue?